# How to create Full Text Index via Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, full-text-indexing

I can create Unique Constraint on a column in Hibernate mapping by

```
@Table(name = "table_name", uniqueConstraints = {
           @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"column_with_unique_value"}) })
```

If I want to add Index to a specified column

```
@Column(name = "index_column", nullable = false)
@Index
private String indexColumn;
```

So out of 3 indexes possible in mysql (unique, index, full_text), I can able to create two of the indexes (unique, index) via hibernate mapping annotation. But I can't seem to find any annotations or documentation for creating `Full Text Index`.

MySQL version : 5.7.x.

Hibernate version : 4.2.7.Final

Searching for Full Text Index creation mostly returns results related to hibernate search and Lucene. Is there any hibernate annotation available to create `Full Text Index` directly in MySQL INNODB table..? (just like the `@UniqueConstraint` or `@Index` annotation)